# How can I adding `transition` to my Popup

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a popup, popup revealing with `setTimeout()` in 2 seconds but I can't give it a `transition` It's showing suddenly and bumping it to the screen. I don't want that but I can't add a `transition` from CSS, I don't know why. Am I missing something? I don't understand pls help me out I'm curious why is it not happening.

```
<div class="popup" v-if="PopupBtn" >
                <transition name="fade">
                    <div class="popup-inner card" >
                        <slot />
                        <h2 class="fw-bolder">Suggested Offer</h2>
                        <p class="fw-bold my-4"> Do you want 2 times faster connection with a difference of 1$? </p>
                        <p> <i class="fas fa-check-circle me-2" style="color: limegreen;"></i>30 days money back guarantee</p>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center my-4">
                            <button class="popup-close my-3 btn btn-success w-100 py-3" @click="CloseBtn(); updateProgress();"> Yes </button>
                            <button class="popup-close btn btn-light w-100 py-3" @click="CloseBtn(); updateProgress();"> No </button>
                        </div>
                        <p> 97% of our users choose YES. </p>
                    </div>
                </transition>
</div>



export default {
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            todos: [
                { text: "Your answers are being analyzed.", progress: 20 },
                { text: "Account setup in progress.", progress: 40 },
                { text: "Server location setup is in progress.", progress: 60 },
                { text: "Your account is being created.", progress: 100 }
            ],
            progress: 0,
            PopupBtn: false,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        startProgress() {
            if ( this.progress < 75 ) {
                this.progress += 1;
            }
        },
        finishProgress(){
            if ( this.progress < 100 ) {
                this.progress += 1;
            }
            if (this.progress == 100 ) {
                setTimeout( () => this.$router.push({ path: '/tenthPage'}), 2000);
            }
        },
        updateProgress() {
            setInterval(this.finishProgress, 50)
        },
        buttonTrigger1() {
            this.PopupBtn = !this.PopupBtn;
            console.log("Popup is toggled");
        },
        CloseBtn() {
            console.log("Popup is closed");
            this.PopupBtn = false;
        },
    },
    created() {
        setInterval(this.startProgress, 1);
        setTimeout(this.buttonTrigger1 , 2000);
    }
}


<style>
.popup{
 position: fixed;  
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 99;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 transition: 2s;
 }

.popup-inner{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: 2s;
}
</style>
```

Comment: because your popup already there, and you just show it by if condition. you need to add class which has transition in it.

Comment: I did all I understand sorry please dont give up on me 

`<div class="popup" :class="active" v-if="PopupBtn" >
                    <transition name="fade">
                        <div class="popup-inner card active" :class="active">
  data() {
                progress: 0,
                PopupBtn: false,
                isActive: true,
            }
        }

<style>
.active{
    transition: 2s !important;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you've set to "fade" the name of the transition your calling, but there are no such css styles for this transition.

As shown in Vue docs (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/transitions-enterleave.html#transitioning-single-elements-components), you have to define the transition classes like this :

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Where leave-active / enter-active defines how the transition s hould be applied (which properties, duration, ...) and enter-from / enter-leave defines the actual mutated css properties and their values.

You have above a very basic working fade transition.

Comment: it doesn't work man It's still suddenly bumping it to the screen.

Comment: Can you upload a minimal reproduction of your issue on github or even better on stackblitz ? Anyway here's an example I made for you on stackblitz, you can see it works as I described. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3pcvqu

Comment: Dude, it worked thank you. I'm trying to be a good developer and a good StackOverflower. I take into account what you say. I can see now ı don't know the `ref` thing that's why